android.security.KeyStoreException: Unsupported purpose when hashing - using PURPOSE_SIGN
I am using Android KeyStore in Kotlin. Right now I am having an issue where I am loading keys in, and later when I retrieve them I use them to encrypt, decrypt, and generate a hash. Encrypt/decrypt works fine, but hashing does not. My KeyStore code is as follows:
private fun loadKey(fullAlias: String, key: SecretKey) {
        val keyEntry = KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(SecretKeySpec(key.encoded, AES_ALG))
        val prot: ProtectionParameter = KeyProtection.Builder(
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA1)
            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
            .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
            .build();
        keyStore.setEntry(fullAlias, keyEntry, prot)
    }

I hash as follows:
private const val HMAC_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256"

fun pibaseToken(key: Key, label: ByteString): ByteString {
//        val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(key.encoded, HMAC_ALGORITHM)
        val mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_ALGORITHM)
        mac.init(key)
        val token = mac.doFinal(label.toByteArray())
        return ByteString.copyFrom(token)
    }

The error I keep getting is that the purpose is unsupported.                                                                                                     2: Error::Km(r#UNSUPPORTED_PURPOSE)) (public error code: 13 internal Keystore code: -2). Any thoughts would be appreciated. (note: I know some security practices here are not ideal, but I am making a proof-of-concept).

Are you trying to use your AES key as an HMAC key?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk yes, that is correct. Is that not possible to do here? If so, any thoughts on how I could use the AES key for HMAC?
